Sending data from multiple REST APIs to a single kinesis stream and then load them in separate s3 storage path
I have multiple REST APIs for example one giving pricing information and another for product information etc.. in my streaming data pipeline I am sending data to a single kinesis stream from these multiple REST API's using AWS Lambda function and have one fire hose stream using which I am loading data to an S3 path.
The data is in JSON format.
In this case the JSON  file that firehose is loading to S3 path has data from all the APIs I am hitting, my end goal is to load this data to databricks delta live tables. It would be easier if I can separate the S3 buckets and load the Json from each REST API to a separate S3 path and then build databricks volumes of off those S3 paths to load data to the databricks delta live tables.
looking for any best practices using which I can simplify this flow.

Below is my lambda function:
import json
import boto3
import base64
import requests
import os
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def getprice():
url=f'''https://getpriceyxyz'''

return url

def getproduct():
url = f'''https://getproduct''

return url

def lambda_handler(event, context):
functions_to_call=['getprice','getproduct']

for function in functions_to_call:
    if function in globals() and callable(globals()[function]):
        url = globals()[function]()
        api_to_kinesis(user, passwd, url, function)
        

def api_to_kinesis(user, passwd, url, function_name):
try:
# Calling  REST API
    response = requests.get(url, auth=("{}".format(user), "{}".format(passwd)))
    result = response.text



    # Parse the original JSON
    parsed_data = json.loads(result)
    
    # Serialize the parsed JSON back to a string
    serialized_data = json.dumps(parsed_data["results"]["items"], separators=(',', ':'), sort_keys=True)

    # Kinesis stream
    try:
        kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')
        print("printing kinesis_client:",kinesis_client)
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        partition_key = str(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        if partition_key is None:
            partition_key = "A"
        kinesis_response = kinesis_client.put_record(
            
            StreamName='stream-name',
            Data=serialized_data,
            PartitionKey=partition_key)
        print("printing kinesis_response:",kinesis_response)
    
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error in Kinesis_stream processing")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error in retrieving the  url: ",url)  

Below is my sample json from s3 path, where data from both product and price API is clubbed:
{"results":{"items":[{"priceA":"85.15","date":"4/2/2024 12:00:00 PM","priceB":"85.5","priceC":"83.85"},{"priceA":"85.43","date":"4/3/2024 12:00:00 PM","priceB":"86.2","priceC":"84.85"},null],"status":"OK"}}{"results":{"items":[{"productA":"ab","date":"4/2/2024 12:00:00 PM","productB":"gh"},{"productA":"ff","date":"4/3/2024 12:00:00 PM","productB":"ru"},null],"status":"OK"}}
